# Get value from 2nd list based on ID from 1st list in Python

Tags: python, loops

I'm a beginner in Python and have a file i've read in that has an Market_ID field.  While looping over this file (list), I need to access the Market_name in a 2nd file (Market_ID,Market_Name).

What's the best place for me to start? I can give more detail on what the program is doing if necessary.

The files(lists) are laid out as follows:

```
File1:  Cust_ID, Market_ID, Cust_Name, IsNew
File2:  Market_ID, Market_Name
```

My main loop is over File1.  I need to be able to access the Market_Name from File2 to be able to place it in a new file i'm creating from data in File1.  Hope that helps.

Comment: How about showing the some examples of your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the files are not too big (a few megabytes) you could store each item in a dict() using the Market_ID as key.
>
> This looks like data drom a database - if you are familiar with
>   relational databases and their use you could insert each file into a
>   separate table and then perform queries. Python has an interface to
>   sqlite in its standard library.
>
> For solving this quickly I suggest to use dicts though.
>   BY -- ***[sleeplessnerd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/616486/sleeplessnerd)***

[More about dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html),
[More about sqlite](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html)

```
file2 = open("/path/to/file2", "r")
market_names = {}
for line in file2:
  fields = line.split(",")
  market_names[int(fields[0])] = fields[1]
file2.close()

file1 = open("/path/to/file1", "r")
for line in file1:
  fields = line.split(",")
  market_name = market_names[int(fields[1])]
  # do what ever you want with the Market_Name associated with
  # the Market_ID contained in this line
file1.close()
```

Comment: With a few small adjustments, this works now.  Thanks @Nicoretti and everyone else for the input.

Answer (score 1):

If the files are not too big (a few megabytes) you could store each item in a dict() using the Market_ID as key.

This looks like data drom a database - if you are familiar with relational databases and their use you could insert each file into a separate table and then perform queries. Python has an interface to sqlite in its standard library.

For solving this quickly I suggest to use dicts though.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, could you please supply more details?

When you say file(list) do you mean that you've created a list that contains all the data you need from the first file? what about the second file?

If they are both lists than something like this would work:

```
for market_id in flie1_list:
    for pair in file2_list:
        if pair[0] == market_id: 
            market_name = pair[1]
            break
    <keep doing whatever it is you need to do in first loop>
```

Note - I'm fairly a beginner as well, and it's my first answer on this site. Go easy ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not up on my python, but conceptually, what you'll probably want to do is read the second file into a [`dictionary`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html) first and then look up the id in the dictionary to get the associated name.  Alternatively, if the ids are numeric and more-or-less dense, you could just read them into a regular array.